# How to deal with extra whitespace that comes with custom fonts?

Tags: css, typography, typeface

I am using custom font-face in my web app and as demonstrated by image bellow it comes with this extra whitespace underneath it which makes alignment a bit tricky in elements like buttons for example.

I tried playing with different line heights, but it didn't change it. I believe space below it is needed for some ligatures of this typeface which is fine. But can I add extra space above as well to sort of match it all and make alignment easier? Preferably with css.

[image]

Comment: use different value for padding-top/bottom to rectify this .. you cannot really control that space without editing the font

Comment: [vertical-align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) might be what you're looking for. There are also tools around to change the vertical metrics of your font, [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/)s font generator does support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line-height` property in css to either reduce the height vertically.

similarly, you can use `padding-top` to add space on top of the text